# ggplot with facets and geom_abline

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Suppose I have data like these:

```
n <- 100
set.seed(123)    
df <- data.frame(
    num1 = rnorm(n),
    num2 = sample(1:4, n, replace = TRUE),
    char = sample(c("Green", "Red", "Blue"), n, replace = TRUE),
    fac  = factor(sample(c("Green", "Red", "Blue"), n, replace = TRUE)),
    logical = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = TRUE),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I'd like to generate a ggplot **with facets and reference lines** so that the reference lines are plotted in the appropriate facet.  For instance:

```
## Base plot
ggplot(df, aes(num2, num1)) + 
geom_jitter() + 
facet_grid(~ char)
```

[image]

Now I'd like to add vertical lines whenever `logical == TRUE`.

[image]

Something like:

```
## Does not work
ggplot(df, aes(num2, num1)) + 
geom_jitter() + 
facet_grid(~ char) +
geom_vline(xintercept = num2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map your xintercept value inside of `aes()`, to tell ggplot to look inside of `data` for it. And subset the data for just that layer, based on your conditional.

```
ggplot(df, aes(num2, num1)) + 
    geom_jitter() + 
    facet_grid(~ char) +
    geom_vline(data = df[df$logical == TRUE,], aes(xintercept = num2))
```

[image]